# OpenLayers 3 Map creation not centering

Tags: openlayers-3

I have the following very simple code:

```
@map_center = [-32.951106, -60.669952]
@map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map-canvas',
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: @map_center,
          zoom: 5
        })
    })
```

It's in coffeescript, but you will get the idea. The problem is, the map does not center at all. It gets stuck in [0, 0]
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the view's projection is Web Mercator (EPSG:3857). This means the view center's coordinates should be expressed in that projection.

If you have latitudes and longitudes you can use the `ol.proj.transform` function to transform the latitudes longitudes to Web Mercator coordinates. For example:

```
var view = new ol.View({
  zoom: 4,
  center: ol.proj.transform([-60, -32], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally moved to leaflet... covered the entire app in a fraction of the time needed